# VisJS: Improve rendering time for dynamic nodes(5 to 5000 nodes)

Tags: javascript, vis.js, vis.js-network

I have a requirement to display dynamic nodes (5 to 5000) when user double click any of the existing nodes.

When number of child node is more than 100, my network taking more time to stabilize. I am not sure how many child nodes I will get for that selected node. so, I can't use `storeposition()`.

Can someone suggest me how to precalculate node positions or someother idea which will improve my rendering time?

Please find my configuration and code sample below

```
physics: {
  barnesHut: {
    gravitationalConstant: -2000,
    centralGravity: 0.3,
    springLength: 95,
    springConstant: 0.04,
    damping: 0.09
  },
  maxVelocity: 146,
  solver: 'barnesHut',
  timestep: 0.35,
  stabilization: {
    enabled: true,
    iterations: 2000,
    updateInterval: 25
  }
}
```

[Plunker:Sample app which will load 5000 nodes dynamically](https://plnkr.co/edit/3PF4X4TznVqCJxJOWKC9?p=preview)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add the property

```
physics: false
```

and then back to you physics definition.
add this property to your edges too.

[see plunker here](https://plnkr.co/edit/JW38PpTEjATsg74fv1Od?p=preview)